# Accessing Shipping Rate object data in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

I want to get the possible shipping methods in Woocommerce. I can get to the Class WC_Shipping_Rate class but i don't know how to get 'deeper' and it's driving me crazy.

Here's my code:

```
$packages = WC()->shipping->get_packages();

foreach ( $packages as $i => $package ) {

    foreach($package['rates'] as $value){
        echo '<pre>'.var_export($value, true).'</pre>';
    }

}
```

This piece of code prints this on my screen:

```
WC_Shipping_Rate::__set_state(array(
   'data' => 
  array (
    'id' => 'flat_rate:1',
    'method_id' => 'flat_rate',
    'instance_id' => 1,
    'label' => 'Per post',
    'cost' => '2.50',
    'taxes' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
   'meta_data' => 
  array (
    'Items' => '1 Kip × 1',
  ),
))
WC_Shipping_Rate::__set_state(array(
   'data' => 
  array (
    'id' => 'free_shipping:2',
    'method_id' => 'free_shipping',
    'instance_id' => 2,
    'label' => 'Download kaart',
    'cost' => '0.00',
    'taxes' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
   'meta_data' => 
  array (
    'Items' => '1 Kip × 1',
  ),
))
```

My question is: How can i access the `data` array and then the `label` value? I know how to get the `label` value, but i cant 'reach' the `data`...

I have tried to get it using methods, more arrays but the `WC_Shipping_Rate::__set_state(array(` is confusing me. Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following using [`WC_Shipping_Rate` methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Shipping_Rate.html) or directly the properties:

```
// Loop though shipping packages
foreach ( WC()->shipping->get_packages() as $key => $package ) {
    // Loop through Shipping rates
    foreach($package['rates'] as $rate_id => $rate ){

        echo $rate->get_label(). '<br>';

        // Or:
        echo $rate->label. '<br>';
    }
}
```

Tested and works.